# Vaadin-spring View injection: any alternative to @SpringView so injection is controlled from UI?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

We all (hopely) know the standard way of registring views into vaadin-spring:

```
@SpringView(name = "")
public class ViewMain implements View {
    // ...
}

@SpringView(name = "login")
public class ViewLogin implements View {
    // ...
}

@SpringUI(path = "")
public class MainUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @override
    protected void init(....) {

        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);

        ...
    }

}
```

Now I have more than one UI, `ViewLogin` sits into different common component and I need to add some of UI with `ViewLogin`.

- I cannot add UI list to `@SpringView` annotation of `ViewLogin` (it is different package).
- I do not want `ViewLogin` to be present into all UI. More, I need different login views for some of UI as they represent different interfaces.
- Please note `ViewLogin` can have `@Autowired` inside so it should be Spring managed. Just `navigator.addView(...)` does not work.

Can I do something as close as possible to `@SpringView` annotation but from UI side?

Answer (score 0):

Scouted around sources - practically it is not possible to configure applicable `UI` for `View` other than through `@SprngView` annotation.

As for current solution the following configuration from `UI` class worked as expected:

```
@SpringUI(path = "")
public class MainUI extends UI {

    // Now we need to configure views.
    @SpringView(name = ViewMain.NAME, ui = {MainUI.class})
    static private class OurViewMain extends ViewMain {}

    @SpringView(name = ViewLogin.NAME, ui = {MainUI.class})
    static private class OurViewLogin extends ViewLogin {}

    @override
    protected void init(....) {
        ....
    }

}
```

So practically I extend views without any change and annotate 'derived' classes. This allows to code view in one place and assign it to UI (or multiple UI) in another one. This makes possible different naming for the same view into different UI.

Hope soon `@SpringView` configuration will be less linear and will allow something like this. I don't see any problem to implement this.